# Running into502 bad gateway / nginx error while deploying Node js backend to AWS ELB, also using AWS RDS postgres which is already deployed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The compilation is complete in all logs but am retrieving this error message:

"http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.30.177"
2022/12/01 21:42:06 [error] 32487#32487: *55 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.42.14, server: , request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/.env", host: "54.242.94.106"

Along with in my environment I am getting this response as well:

Environment health has transitioned from Degraded to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. Initialization completed 86 seconds ago and took 2 minutes. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances. Impaired services on all instances.

I am trying to host the server on aws and this is my server:

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT
const cors = require('cors')
const pizzaRouter = require('./api/pizza/pizza-router')
const toppingsRouter = require('./api/toppings/toppings-router')


server.use(express.json())
server.use(cors())
server.use('/api/pizza',pizzaRouter)
server.use('/api/toppings',toppingsRouter)



server.get('/', (req,res) => res.json({message:'This better work'}))
server.listen( PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on PORT ${PORT} `)
})
```

// I did not assign the PORT env to any number as it has not worked for any i have assigned so far(443, 5000)

Comment: Where is your application running (EC2, ECS etc)? Are you able to access it from within the instance of through IP without using the ELB?

Comment: Running on an EC2, i go to the instances and the instance state is green but the application is degarded. I just attempted to connect the instance in EC2 dashboard to my application environment and getting this error: EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see Set up EC2 Instance Connect at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html.